# How to make bot not mention user

Tags: javascript, discord.js

My code:

```
if (msg.startsWith(prefix + 'DM')) {
  message.delete()
  if (message.channel instanceof Discord.DMChannel);
  else if (!message.member.roles.some(r => ["ugc-mod"] + ["ugc-admin"] + ["ugc-manager"].includes(r.name))) return message.reply(":x: Sorry, you don't have permissions to use this!");
  var member = message.mentions.members.first();
  if (!member)
    return message.reply(":x: Please mention a valid member of this server");
  var dmMessage = args.join(` `);
  var embedhelpmember = new Discord.RichEmbed()
    .setTitle("Message:")
    .addField(`Server:`, message.guild.name)
    .addField("Message:", "`" + dmMessage + "`")
    .addField("From:", message.author);
  member.send(embedhelpmember);
  message.delete();
}
```

What I get when I do the dm commandtries [image]

The bot trys do mention the user that it is sending the dm to, how would i make it so it does not mention the user at all?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either decide to write the name without the mention or to not show the name at all.
If you want not to display any name, delete the line with:

```
.addField("From:", message.author);
```

If you want to display their name change it into one of the following:

```
.addField("From:", message.author.tag); // 'UserName#1234'
.addField("From:", message.member.displayName); // 'MemberNickName in the guild'
```

If you want to remove that plain mention in the `Message` field, use [`Array.shift()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift) before joining the array.

```
args.shift();
var dmMessage = args.join(` `);
```

Comment: Happy to hear that :)

Comment: if `message.author.tag` gives UserName#1234, you can just slice that to get just the username. You could do `message.author.tag.slice(0, message.author.tag.length - 5);`

Answer (score 0):

Delete the line: `.addField("From:", message.author)`

Comment: @Cal I don't see where it tries to mention the user. The image provided only shows the Server name and the ID of the message send.